# Saving pdf in user folder

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

In my windows form, i am using iTextSharp to generate pdf.

I have hardcoded the location where the pdf will be saved, but i would like to ask user for the location to save this pdf. How can i perform this?

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
  {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
      g.CopyFromScreen(this.Location, new Point(0, 0), this.Size);
    }
    Document doc = new Document();
    iTextSharp.text.Image i = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(b, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\output.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(this.Size.Width + doc.LeftMargin + doc.RightMargin, this.Size.Height + doc.TopMargin + doc.BottomMargin));

    doc.Open();
    doc.Add(i);
    doc.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: open0 dialog box and get file location from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) to display a standard save dialog, which would allow the user to select where he wants the file to be saved.

Example of usage:

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Title = "Save file as...";
dialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dialog.FileName);
}
```

Of course, you have to use `dialog.FileName` when creating your FileStream:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: if i create method with above code called save() and call this method instead of new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\output.pdf", it doesnot work

Comment: You have to use `dialog.FileName` when creating your `FileStream`.